# VAPIX send audio to axis ip camera

Tags: c#, audio, sdk, speaker, vapix

I have a axis cam with speaker output.  I've installed on my Notebook the Vapix Library and now I can receive the videos in MEPEG-4 format.

Now I want to send the audio captured from my notebook to the camera with the same Library.

Finally I've searched this document but I don't know how to use this in C#.

[Vapix Audio SDK](http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_audio_43309_en_1108.pdf)

Comment: Hi boys.. i've solved... if you are interested wirte me a PM.

Comment: you can always answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: Cannot send private messages on StackOverflow. Please write down the solution you found here as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @Antonio Cannot send you a PM could you show how you connect to the camera to get videos in MP4 not ASF format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VapixForToroRosso
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string USER = "root";
    private string PASS = "Blescia";
    private string IP = "192.168.1.2";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axAxisMediaControl1.Volume = 100; //Set the volume of speaker
        /*
         *Use this if the camera required the login
         */
        axAxisMediaControl1.MediaUsername = USER; //Set the username
        axAxisMediaControl1.MediaPassword = PASS; //Set the password
        axAxisMediaControl1.Mute = false; //Disable Mute    
        axAxisMediaControl1.EnableReconnect = true; //Reconnect to the camera automatically

        axAxisMediaControl1.MediaURL = "rtsp://192.168.1.2/mpeg4/media.amp"; //For Retrieve the video streaming
        axAxisMediaControl1.AudioConfigURL = "http://" + IP + "/axis-cgi/view/param.cgi?camera=1&action=list&group=Audio,AudioSource.A0"; //Pre-Configuration of Camera
        axAxisMediaControl1.AudioTransmitURL = "http://" + IP + "/axis-cgi/audio/transmit.cgi"; //Url to send the streaming AUDIO          

        axAxisMediaControl1.Play();
    }

    private void btnStartStreaming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axAxisMediaControl1.AudioTransmitStart(); //Start the streaming to camera
    }

    private void btnStopStreaming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axAxisMediaControl1.AudioTransmitStop(); //Stop the streaming the camera
    }
   }
}
```